# ADF :: How to substitute files in Blob Storage

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, azure-automation, azure-workflow-automation

In the Azure Cost Management > Export, there is an export called `Daily export of month-to-date`:

[image]

Such export happens daily and it's exported to a Blob Storage.

**PROBLEM:** Because it's a month-to-day export, if today it's the 26 or April, today it will create a .csv file with all the Cost Management information from the 1th of April to the 26th.

But tomorrow another .csv file will be generated with all the costs from the 1th of April to the 27th.

This way I will have double informations!

**GOAL:** an ideal solution would be that as soon as a new file is exported to that Storage Account the old file is deleted.

So there is always only 1 .csv file that contains all the data from month-to-date.

**SCOPE:** Everything can be in scope:

- Azure Data Factory
- Logic Apps
- Automation Accounts
- Power Automate

...whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**Design:**

[image]
Clearly:
[image]
[image]
You can reproduce the above design with below code:

**Logic app code:**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Delete_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "SkipDeleteIfFileNotFoundOnServer": false
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "delete",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('/rithwik/',variables('ammo')))}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "value": "@triggerBody()?['LastModified']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Append_to_array_variable_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "vammo",
                            "value": "@items('For_each')?['DisplayName']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@items('For_each')?['LastModified']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_string_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "ammo",
                                    "value": "@variables('vammo')[0]"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Append_to_string_variable_2": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "name": "ammo",
                                        "value": "@variables('vammo')[1]"
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "less": [
                                        "@ticks(variables('emo')[0])",
                                        "@ticks(variables('emo')[1])"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "vammo",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "ammo",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmcml0aHdpaw=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcml0aHdpaw==": "/rithwik"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)_2": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmcml0aHdpaw==",
                        "maxFileCount": 1
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcml0aHdpaw==": "/rithwik"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-74c23f/resourceGroups/rbojja-/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b8b-b5ba-2074c23f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly have 1 blob like below:

[image]

Blob can be of any type.

Then Uploaded new Blob:

[image]

Then blob got deleted:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Also added some other new steps to be more accurate:**
[image]
**Code view:**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Delete_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "SkipDeleteIfFileNotFoundOnServer": false
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "delete",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('/rithwik/',variables('xyz')))}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_4": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "value": "@triggerBody()?['LastModified']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Append_to_array_variable_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "vammo",
                            "value": "@items('For_each')?['DisplayName']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@items('For_each')?['LastModified']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_string_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "ammo",
                                    "value": "@variables('vammo')[0]"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "actions": {
                                "Compose_2": {
                                    "inputs": "@variables('vammo')[1]",
                                    "runAfter": {},
                                    "type": "Compose"
                                },
                                "Set_variable": {
                                    "inputs": {
                                        "name": "ammo",
                                        "value": "@{outputs('Compose_2')}"
                                    },
                                    "runAfter": {
                                        "Compose_2": [
                                            "Succeeded"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "type": "SetVariable"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "less": [
                                        "@ticks(variables('emo')[0])",
                                        "@ticks(variables('emo')[1])"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable_2": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "vammo",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "ammo",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_4": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "xyz",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@variables('ammo')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded",
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmcml0aHdpaw=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcml0aHdpaw==": "/rithwik"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)_2": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmcml0aHdpaw==",
                        "maxFileCount": 1
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcml0aHdpaw==": "/rithwik"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b8074c23f/resourceGroups/bojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c574c23f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to test this

Comment: @Francesco Mantovani, Sure

Comment: I have a question @RithwikBojja: in the line 248 why it's asking for a ManagedApi id?

Comment: Its actually came  by deafult while i was designing the logic app, I am sure answer will help you

Comment: What is the first action? I cannot find it in the list of Logic Apps

Comment: When a blob is added or modified

Comment: I wanted to thank you for the effort. In the end I used a Logic App that is slightly different . Thank you for your effort

Comment: Glad that you appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

With blob storage, writing a file with the same name to the same location will automatically overwrite the existing one. I'm not too familiar with cost management, but you can use an ADF pipeline and set the sink as your blob storage account container, and ensure the file is the same name so it will automatically overwrite the existing e.g. fileApril.csv will overwrite fileApril.csv.
You can also set parameters in ADF to change naming convention to retain versioning e.g. using dynamic date() parameter should allow you to keep a file per month based on when the pipeline was run.

Comment: That would be great, I will try now

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your ide. Unfortunately the file is created with a different name every day. But I liked your idea. Thank you

Comment: Your idea should receive not only my thumb up: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/156ca19e-7900-ee11-a81c-6045bdbc2a74