# How to extract information from for each loop in azure logic app

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-logic-apps

Probably simple, but I cannot find anything to help me with this. In short, I just want to extract information from a for each loop. I can't set variable within the loop (the updated value is local to the scope and doesn't persist once the loop ends) I can't extract information from a compose (again, data is local to the loop and inaccessible outside of it) and I'm running out of options. Something I haven't tried is using an array, but I would prefer to avoid that if at all possible. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, too ambiguous. Show us some data, your flow and what you  expect as an outcome. Will be easier to help and be more specific with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to extract information from for each loop in azure logic app

For that you can use Empty variable initialization before for each loops like below:

[image]

You can also use an empty array variable, here I have used string.

Then you can append or set this variable inside the for each loop like below:

[image]

As you havent provided input assuming an example input and output is:

[image]

You can also use compose and then set too like below:

[image]

Example references where i used for each loop and variables are [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76109116/adf-how-to-substitute-files-in-blob-storage/76109814?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C0.0000#76109814) and  [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76363362/retrieve-value-of-array-by-key-logic-apps/76363982?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#76363982).

This is the process where you are initializing variable globally and using it inside the loops and then doing the necessary actions on it.